# Copying data between groups in a grouped df

Tags: r, dplyr

I have grouped data that has blocks of missing values. I used `dplyr` to compute the sum of my target variable over each group. For groups where the sum is zero, I want to replace that group's values with the ones from the previous group. I could do this in a loop, but since my data is in a large data frame, that would be extremely inefficient.

Here's a synthetic example:

```
df <- tbl_df(as.data.frame(cbind(c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4)), 
                           c(abs(rnorm(4)), rep(NA, 4)))))

names(df) <- c("group", "var")

df <- df %>%
        group_by(group) %>%
        mutate(total = sum(var, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: group

  group       var   total
1     1 1.3697267 4.74936
2     1 1.5263502 4.74936
3     1 0.4065596 4.74936
4     1 1.4467237 4.74936
5     2        NA 0.00000
6     2        NA 0.00000
7     2        NA 0.00000
8     2        NA 0.00000
```

In this case, I want to replace the values of `var` in group 2 with the values of `var` in group 1, and I want to do it by detecting that `total = 0` in group 2.

I've tried to come up with a custom function to feed into `do()` that does this, but can't figure out how to tell it to replace values in the current group with values from a different group. With the above example, I tried the following, which will always replace using the values from group 1:

```
CheckDay <- function(x) { 
  if( all(x$total == 0) ) { x$var <- df[df$group==1, 2] } ; x 
}

do(df, CheckDay)
```

CheckDay does return a df, but `do()` throws an error:

```
Error: Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: I'm willing to use base or data.table if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on. First you need to make sure `df` is a `data.frame`, your function `CheckDay(x)` has both the local variable `x` which you give value `df` as the global variable `df` itself, it's better to keep everything inside the function local. Finally, your call to `do(df, CheckDay(.))` is missing the `(.)` part. Try this, this should work:

```
library("dplyr")

df <- tbl_df(as.data.frame(cbind(c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4)), 
                                 c(abs(rnorm(4)), rep(NA, 4)))))

names(df) <- c("group", "var")

df <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(var, na.rm = TRUE))
df <- as.data.frame(df)


CheckDay <- function(x) {
  if( all( (x[x$group == 2, ])$total == 0) ) { 
    x$var <- x[x$group == 1, 2] 
  }  
  x 
}

result <- do(df, CheckDay(.))
print(result)
```

Comment: I thought I'd need to use df as effectively a global variable inside CheckDay (taking advantage of the fact that it will always exist in CheckDay's parent environment). I see that isn't necessary. Thank you! But I still need to figure out how to generalize it so that for a larger data frame it will get values from the previous group (rather than a specified group as in the example). Perhaps I can group on a factor and use the factor levels as a proxy?

Comment: You should easily be able to loop over all group numbers, store them in a vector. Whenever all group totals are `0` grab the previous entry in your group vector and set `var` accordingly.

Comment: The loop is what I want hoping to avoid, since I have 5788 groups. But once I have the indices of the zero data, which I can get from df$total==0, I can replace only those indices with values from a pre-shifted copy of df$var.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Brouwer's answer, here is what I implemented to accomplish my goal:

- Generate `df` as previously.
- Create `df.shift`, a copy of df with groups 1, 1, 2... etc -- i.e. a df with the variables shifted down by one group. (The rows in group 1 of `df.shift` could also simply be blank.)
- Get the indices where `total = 0` and copy the values from `df.shift` into `df` at those indices.

This can all be done in base R. It creates one copy, but is much cheaper and faster than looping over the groups.